# Potential Security Breach

Tags: macbook-pro

My display went black suddenly while I was online banking. I tried to do a hard shutdown but had no control over my keyboard. After approximately one to one and half minutes of attempting shutdown, the screen with my banking info reappeared. Any ideas? Was I breached? I checked my firewall and it showed as turned on. I also checked to make sure all share settings were turned off and they were. What else can I do to protect my info. especially while online.

Comment: are you using HTTPS in browser? Just in case.... change your password.

Comment: Maybe look for hardware problems, not a breach.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem.